# Displaying Info. In Gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm doing a web application in asp.net. It is a fitness app. where members register onto the site, insert different exercises they have been doing and they can also join a group of a fitness club.

When I register for a club, I have all of the members of that club displayed in a Gridview and I have the select button in the Gridview selected. When the select button is hit, I want to be able to see what exercises people have been doing which is stored in the AssignPlan table ie Run, Gym work etc.

However when I display this information, I do it using a session to get the specific information of who ever is logged in. But for the groups I want people to see other people's information but sessions will not work for me as the person who's info. I want to bring up is not logged in.

When I am displaying my own information, this is the code I use:

```
SqlDataAdapter dadapter;
DataSet dset;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString");
string sql = "select * from ExerciseType";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblRegistered.Text = Session["Name"].ToString();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        dset = new DataSet();
        dadapter.Fill(dset);
        DropDownList1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
        DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ExerciseType";
        DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ExerciseType";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();

        GridViewBind();

    }
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewBind();
}


public void GridViewBind()
{

    dadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ExerciseName FROM ExerciseDisplay Where TypeName = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);

    dset = new DataSet();
    dadapter.Fill(dset);
    GridView1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

Is there any way of doing this? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what you want done but I think a querystring could help you. You simply navigate to a new page with the person's ID as the query string. Use the ID to retrieve the person's information.

Comment: So just to clarify, all members that are part of a group have their own exercises that they have inputted in an Exercise Form. I'm trying to click on a member and that brings me through to the Exercise Form which displays their exercises which they have already inserted. So yes I think you are on the right track with retrieving an ID and maybe placing their username onto a label and retrieving their exercises from that. How would I go about retrieving the ID? I am very new to c# and am struggling a bit. Do you have any code that would help me?

Comment: Just like you got the username from the session, from the list of other users in your Gridview, your link could have a querystring part like `relateduser.aspx?username=john`. That takes you to another page where you can retrieve the username from the querystring and use it to display the exercises for the user. Two pages, one using username from session and the other using username from querystring but the page have the same logic just the source of username is different. Google HyperlinkColumn for GridView on how to generate link from fields in the Gridview

Answer (score 0):

You've 2 solutions:

1. In the First Grid set the DataKeyNames property as User Id, then add another Grid and in its Data Source make a Where clause that use `GridView1.SelectedValue` to get user exercises.
   Here's an example when you select company the 2nd GridView will display its contact persons
2. Add hyperlink row to your GridView which Url for another form where you'll display user's exercises and pass user Id as QueryString.

Example on solution 1:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Comp_CompanyId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_CompanyId" HeaderText="Comp_CompanyId" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Comp_CompanyId"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Name" HeaderText="Comp_Name" SortExpression="Comp_Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Type" HeaderText="Comp_Type" SortExpression="Comp_Type"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Status" HeaderText="Comp_Status" SortExpression="Comp_Status"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Select" Text="Select" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRMConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Comp_CompanyId], [Comp_Name], [Comp_Type], [Comp_Status] FROM [Company]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pers_FirstName" HeaderText="Pers_FirstName" SortExpression="Pers_FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pers_LastName" HeaderText="Pers_LastName" SortExpression="Pers_LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pers_Salutation" HeaderText="Pers_Salutation" SortExpression="Pers_Salutation" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pers_Title" HeaderText="Pers_Title" SortExpression="Pers_Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pers_MiddleName" HeaderText="Pers_MiddleName" SortExpression="Pers_MiddleName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRMConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Pers_FirstName], [Pers_LastName], [Pers_Salutation], [Pers_Title], [Pers_MiddleName] FROM [Person] WHERE ([Pers_CompanyId] = @Pers_CompanyId)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="Pers_CompanyId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Example on solution 2:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Comp_CompanyId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comp_CompanyId" SortExpression="Comp_CompanyId">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Comp_CompanyId") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkCompany_Id" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Comp_CompanyId") %>' 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Comp_CompanyId","Persons.aspx?CompanyId={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Name" HeaderText="Comp_Name" SortExpression="Comp_Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Type" HeaderText="Comp_Type" SortExpression="Comp_Type"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Comp_Status" HeaderText="Comp_Status" SortExpression="Comp_Status"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRMConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Comp_CompanyId], [Comp_Name], [Comp_Type], [Comp_Status] FROM [Company]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```